# Android App Losing State When Switching Tabs And Orientation

Tags: android, tabs, orientation, state

**The problem:** I have a tabbed android app and I'm losing the content in TabOne whenever I follow these (admittedly strange) steps:

1. Change to another tab.
2. Switch orientation to landscape.
3. Switch orientation back to portrait.
4. Change back to TabOne.

**Android App Description:** I have a pretty bare-bones android app with three tabs that were built using [google's `TabLayout` tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html), we'll call them TabOne, TabTwo, and TabThree. Only TabOne has any content: a simple `EditText` view and `Button` that lets you add text to the body of TabOne. This is rigged up using a custom `ArrayAdapter`, which may have something to do with the strange behavior.

Note that **this does not occur if I change orientation while remaining on TabOne**. This is because I have implemented `OnSaveInstanceState()` and `OnRestoreInstanceState()` to save my list of data in my `TabOneActivity` class.

Comment: I think that is not strange. Android can manage Activities in this way if it thinks it has to free memory because a low resources situation, for example. If the activity is not the foreground activity (I suppose you are using activities as tab content), Android can destroy it and restore it again later. The same for orientation changes. My recommendation is to implement the OnSaveInstanceState and OnRestoreInstanceState if you need to save any state.

Comment: Thanks Jesus, but I do have both of those methods in the activity in question. Is there some sort of additional state I should save in the main activity as well?

Comment: Consider switching from activities-in-tabs to views-in-tabs, as it simplifies this sort of stuff a fair bit. For example, there is only one context to be saved, not one per tab plus one for the hosting activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to restore your activity state in `onCreate`, as well as in `OnRestoreInstanceState`.

I should point out though that this technique is only for transient data, not for long term data storage.  For that you should be saving the data to a database or to `SharedPreferences` in `onPause`, and then retrieving the data in `onResume`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem - the solution I found was to create a 'Dummy' tab and activity for the first tab in the TabLayout onCreate, then in onResume of the Tab Layout Activity, hide the 'Dummy' tab and select the 2nd tab programmatically. Not nice, but works as saves state of 2nd tab (i.e. 1st visible tab).

```
@Override

protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    if (getTabHost() != null && getTabHost().getTabWidget()!= null) {

        getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (getTabHost().getCurrentTab() == 0) {

            getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);

        }

    }

}
```